# How do we pronounce "text's"?

Tags: pronunciation

Is it right to pronounce *text's* as /tekstɪz/ or /teksts/?
I have an inclination to say /tekstɪz/ for example in the phrase *text's chief paradox*.

Comment: Don't say /tekstɪz/. It would be better to say /teks/; it should be one syllable. The most carefully enunciated version would be /teksts/.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a relatively "lazy" speaker - but then again, so are most native speakers. If I contrast...

> 1: *I **text** all day*
>    2: *She **texts** all day*

...it turns out that I don't enunciate the **/t/** at all in the second version (but I *do* "exaggerate" the **/s/**, so it's effectively "stretched-out", or "repeated").

Unless you find it *really* easy to enunciate the consonant sequence **/ksts/**, it's probably not worth even trying. To a first approximation, native speakers will hear what they're *expecting* anyway, unless you're very obviously having trouble getting your mouth parts around what you're trying to say.

---

An even more awkward one is [sixths](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sixth). You won't hear many native speakers fully articulating that one as **/siks-t-ths/**.

Comment: Try "asterisks"!

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team: Nah. I think that one's really easy - people who say ***asteriks*** are probably the same people who say ***aks*** for ***ask***, and ***pacific*** for ***specific*** (I suspect mostly that's people who can't even *read*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "_Acsian_, _axian_, survived in _ax_, down to nearly 1600 the regular literary form, and still used everywhere in midl. and southern dialects, though supplanted in standard English by _ask_, originally the northern form." - OED

Comment: @Colin: No comprende. Are you implying that AAVE **aks** is in some way reflective of a "long and proud history" of a long-established (vernacular?) form? In *my* experience, nearly all people who *currently* say ***aks*** have "non-Anglophone" backgrounds in some way. So I really can't how see the *non-Anglophone* history is particularly relevant to the "timeless" aspect of how it comes about that some people today have problems articulating /s/ after /k/ (but they're fine with the sequence /ks/, which *in my opinion* is "easier").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes, I am, though I'm pointing out that it was once a literary form and only more recently a vernacular form. I was partly reacting to your comment about people who can't even read, though I see that that might have been intended to apply to pacific rather than to ax as well.

Comment: @Colin: Well, I suppose you're more likely to know the truth in this matter than me, but I have to say that without evidence I find it hard to believe the (not just AAVE) tendency to say ***aks*** essentially "derives" in some unbroken chain from a (well-regarded?) "literary" form. It really just looks like sloppy misarticulation reinforced by repetition in certain linguistic subcultures.

Comment: ...and I won't deny that even ***I*** am quite capable of switching consonant clusters around because I find them "awkward". And in my case that can lead me to get the spelling wrong even though in principle I *know* my pronunciation is wrong. Only yesterday I entered ***bowlderise*** into a crossword before eventually having to correct it because I couldn't get other answers to fit in the grid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: there you go again with your evaluative word "sloppy". I don't know the proximate origin of the AAVE word; but the OED says it is "still used" in midland and southern dialects (in England) - "still" may be a century ago, of course. I also know, that if that is how the word is pronounced in some dialect, that that is how the word is pronounced: there's nothing "sloppy" about reproducing the normal sound in that community.

Comment: Well, are you implying that those people who say ***aks*** are actually *unaware* of the "mainstream" pronunciation? I don't say *all* of them are so illiterate that they can't read a three-letter word to derive the "correct" pronunciation, but a goodly proportion fall into that category. And as to "sloppy" - do you deny the relevance of any such concept? Can we not label ***Yeah*** as a "sloppy" version of ***Yes***, for example?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your saying both /s/es. Like  *guess* and *guests*, *tex* and *texts* are minimal pairs in English that can be distinguished with or without the /t/.

Comment: @Araucaria: I think so. Being SE UK, I'm somewhat averse to articulating /t/ in many contexts, but I can't shoehorn a glottal stop into *guests*, so I *think* what I do is just lengthen/exaggerate the /s/. But I'll freely admit that (like many if not most native speakers) there are an awful lot of different phonetic elements that I'm not consciously aware of in either my own or others' speech. (And obviously there are *others*, such as ***aks*** for ***ask*** that stick out like a sore thumb to me! :)

Answer (score 2):

- "text" = /tekst/
- "text's" (and "texts") = /teksts/

You will find some people who use the /tekstɪz/ pronunciation because (admittedly) /teksts/ is challenging. But there is no 'i' in that word.

Comment: **/tekstIz/** ???

Comment: I agree with you, but what about the plural possessive? For example: _They weren't concerned about the **texts'** typos_. Doesn't that get an extra syllable?

Comment: I don't really think you'll find native speakers who say /tekstɪz/.  The consonant cluster can certainly be reduced, but /tekstɪz/ isn't really an option.

Comment: @snailboat, I do. At least when I'm focused.

Answer (score -2):

There is no apostrophe, the way you have used the word (as a plural), but there is if you're using it as a possessive, in saying, for example 'the text's meaning is unclear'.

Comment: That's not a plural, that's a possessive. _The text's chief paradox is the oxymoron in the first two words._